# Сохранить значение элемента Switch С# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Задача: сохранить значение элемента Switch при следующих открытиях приложения (если Switch включен однажды, то чтобы оставался включенным и после перезапуска приложения)
Мой код, который не работает:

```
Context context;
Switch SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                  {    //остальной код
                    context = Application.Context; 
                    SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH=FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH);
                    SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH.CheckedChange += SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH_CheckedChange;  
                  }

    private void SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
            {
                ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();        

                SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH.Checked= prefs.GetBoolean("key_for_kmhtomph", false);

                if (SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH.Checked)
                {
                    SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH.Toggle();
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Off", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                    editor.PutBoolean("key_for_kmhtomph", false);
                    editor.Apply();                
                }
                else
                {
                 SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH.Toggle();
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "On", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                   editor.PutBoolean("key_for_kmhtomph",true);
                   editor.Apply();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Может приложение при выключении стирает данные из ОЗУ? Может нужно настройки хранить в ПЗУ в каком-нибудь файлике?

Comment: @AlexandrPlas как раз для этого и используется SharedPreference

Comment: 1. Насколько я знаю, у свича на xamarin свойство выбора называется IsToggled.
2. Подозрительная логика обработки CheckedChange `SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH.Checked= prefs.GetBoolean("key_for_kmhtomph", false);                if (SettingsSwitchKMHToMPH.Checked)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым. Просто сделал кнопку "Apply", по нажатию которой записывается значение Switch

```
     buttonApply.Click += (sender, e) => 
        {
            if (switchKMHToMPH.Checked == true)
            {
                editor.PutBoolean("key_kmhtomph", true);
                editor.Apply();
            }
            else
            {
                editor.PutBoolean("key_kmhtomph", false);
                editor.Apply();
            }
        };
```